# Can you ignore file or class when xcode is building for iOS Simulator

Tags: swift, xcode, ios-simulator

Some of the framework we use in our project is not working in the iOS simulator. I got it marked as "weak" in target's Build Phase. But still the project can't be build in nay iOS simulator because the some of our class is using the said framework.

Any help is appreciated.

Note, I read some thread in SO but they only talks about "ignoring" some part of the codes but not the file or the whole class.

Comment: Create simulator schema in your project and untarget those files

Comment: What does "is not working" mean? What problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: @matt one of the frameworks we used isn't build to run in iOS Simulator it only runs in real iOS device. But I want to run our app in iOS simulator so I can enable the "malloc guard" which won't work in real device. I checked over the net and found that you can ignore the framework by marking it "weak" in the build phase. Then I have the problem with the files where the framework were called or used.

Comment: Can you solve it with conditional compilation?